# Openlayers 3 vector format with styles

Tags: format, openlayers-3, styling

im using OL3 to display vector maps. Currently im using geojson format. Data are extracted from OpeenStreetMap. The thing is, this format doesnt contain informations about styling, so i have to do it manually and it looks rly baaad.

My friend is developing Android app, and he is using Mapsforge with .map format. Map looks great without styling.

1. Is there any option in OL3 to just load vector data and have it already styled (some other format maybe)?
2. Or are there any dowloadable js code to style geojson?

Comment: could you share the looks of it? Just a screenshot.

Comment: ofc, here http://postimg.org/image/q7o30h01d/

Comment: my efforts haven't been much better. Only thing I can suggest is using opacity for layers, and set it to about 0.6-0.7 to make it blend in a little better. no transparency can be added to objects individually, no shadings etc. I know, its bad.

Comment: All you have to do is to explore [the examples](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/).